# Class template not working with std::string or class object

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am new to C++ templates and I've been struggling to understand why the append() function that I've implemented for my DynamicVector template class:

```
template<class EntityType>
void DynamicVector<EntityType>::append(const EntityType newEntity)
{
    if (this->size == this->capacity) {
        resize();
    }

    this->size += 1;
    this->data[this->size - 1] = newEntity;
}
```

does not work for every data type.

Creating and appending a new element to a dynamic vector of int or char works just fine, but when it comes to a std::string or a class object, even though the declaration appears to work all right(i.e. `DynamicVector<std::string> test_dynamicVectorString` or `DynamicVector<MyClassObject> test_dynamicVectorMyClassObject`), when I try to append an element to the vector:

```
DynamicVector<std::string> test_dynamicVector;
test_dynamicVector.append("asdasd");
```

access violation is thrown:

> Exception thrown at 0x6ED640C9 (vcruntime140d.dll) in DynVect.exe
>   : 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0D3539A8.

I have a dynamically allocated array inside the DynamicVector class(`EntityType* data = new EntityType[capacity];`), where the appended elements are supposed to get stored, and actually are correctly stored when the EntityType is int or char.

But when I try to store strings, debug and step into the append() function, at my *Autos* it appears that the value of `data` is:

> 0x0146539 Error reading characters of string>.<

In fact, the same value appears even when I step into the constructor and `data` gets initialized within the member initialization list:

```
template<class EntityType>
DynamicVector<EntityType>::DynamicVector() : size{ 0 }, capacity{ 1 }, data{ new EntityType[capacity] }
{
}
```

This is the code for DynamicVector class.

```
DynamicVector.h

#pragma once

#include "ErrorMessages.h"


template <class EntityType>
class DynamicVector
{

public:
    DynamicVector();
    DynamicVector(const DynamicVector& original_dynamicVector);
    ~DynamicVector();

    void append(const EntityType newEntity);
    void erase(unsigned int indexToRemove);
    void clear();
    size_t get_size();
    EntityType& operator[](unsigned int index);
    DynamicVector& operator=(const DynamicVector& source);

private:
    const int GROWTH_RATE{ 2 };

    EntityType* data = new EntityType[capacity];
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;

    void resize();
    bool validIndex(int index);
};

/// Contstructor
template<class EntityType>
DynamicVector<EntityType>::DynamicVector() : size{ 0 }, capacity{ 1 }, data{ new EntityType[capacity] }
{
}

/// Copy constructor
template<class EntityType>
DynamicVector<EntityType>::DynamicVector(const DynamicVector& original_dynamicVector)
{
    this->capacity = original_dynamicVector.capacity;
    this->size = original_dynamicVector.size;

    this->data = new EntityType[this->capacity];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->size; ++i) {
        this->data[i] = original_dynamicVector.data[i];
    }
}

/// Destructor
template<class EntityType>
DynamicVector<EntityType>::~DynamicVector()
{
}


/// <summary>
/// Appends the specified new entity to the dynamic vector
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newEntity">The new entity.</param>
template<class EntityType>
void DynamicVector<EntityType>::append(const EntityType newEntity)
{
    if (this->size == this->capacity) {
        resize();
    }

    this->size += 1;
    this->data[this->size - 1] = newEntity;
}


/// <summary>
/// Resizes the dynamic vector, when the capacity gets filled.
/// </summary>
template<class EntityType>
void DynamicVector<EntityType>::resize()
{
    EntityType* resizedSpace{ new EntityType[this->capacity *= GROWTH_RATE] };

    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; ++i) {
        resizedSpace[i] = this->data[i];
    }

    // delete[] this->data;
    this->data = resizedSpace;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, `data` is created before `capacity` is set. So when data is created capacity has indeterminate value. Order of declarations decides here, not order in initialization list.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue, thanks!

Comment: FWIW a decent compiler will warn you about this. Try enabling all the warnings you can (eg. at least `-Wall` for GCC and clang, and at least consider `-Wextra`)

Comment: Thanks.  I would definitey welcome a better compiler after so many struggles :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems that both lead to *undefined behavior* (and for the same reason, uninitialized variables).

The first and most obvious problem is these two lines in the class definition:

```
EntityType* data = new EntityType[capacity];
size_t capacity;
```

Here you will initialize `data` with the help of the ***uninitialized*** member variable `capacity`. Using `capacity` when it's uninitialized will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Since you initialize both `capacity` and `data` in the constructor you don't need the inline initialization of `data`.

---

The second problem is the initialization order in the constructor.

Member variables in the constructor initializer list will be initialized in the order of *declaration* in the class, not the order in the constructor initializer list.

Because you declare the member variables in the order

```
EntityType* data;
size_t capacity;
```

the member `capacity` will be *uninitialized* when you use it for the initialization of `data`. This also leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to change the declaration order to

```
size_t capacity;
EntityType* data;
```

From [this initialization order reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order):

> ... non-static data members are initialized **in order of declaration in the class definition**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Comment: This was the issue, indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`EntityType* data = new EntityType[capacity];` in the class declaration? The only reason that's not a memory leak is because it's Undefined Behavior; capacity is not initialized.